# Asymptotic and 3-SAT problem in Algorithm Course

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, computer-science, computational-complexity, np-complete

my TA says just one of the following is True, anyone could describe me some detail about following three lines?

1- if $f_i$ be a function of natural numbers to natural numbers and $f_i(n)=O(n)$ then $\Sigma_{i=1}^{n} f_i(n)=O(n^2)  $

2- for each positive asymptotic function we have : $ f(n)+ o (f(n))= \theta (f(n)) $

3- if $ L \in NP $  and $ L \leq_p 3-SAT$ (i.e: reduce L to 3-SAT in poly time) then L is NP-Complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - Let be $f_i(n)=in \implies \ \forall i \in \mathbb{N} f_i(n)=O(n)$ and therefore $\sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}}^nf_i(n)=n\sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}}^ni=\Theta(n^3) \implies \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}}^nf_i(n)\neq O(n^2)$ so this statement is false

3 - $\forall P\in {NP}\ P\leq_p 3-SAT$ thus if your statement is true $\forall L\in P\subseteq NP \ L\in NP-complete$ because $3-SAT$ is $NP-complete$ so this statemente is also false

Comment: i think two and three is correct ! but one is false !!!!!

Comment: you are talking about my demonstration or about the statement?

Comment: 2) f(n)+O(f(n))= omega (f(n))+f(n) = theta(f(n))?   3) L in NP and L <=p 3- SAT ,  i means (2) and (3) is true ? am i wrong ?

Comment: i do some edits in question...

Comment: see page 204, (h) on https://books.google.com/books?id=6eIPgTo8AaIC&pg=PA203&lpg=PA203&dq=for+asymptotic+positive+function+f%28n%29+o%28f%28n%29%29+%3D&source=bl&ots=siEO6SiF-U&sig=B8MJqQXc3UsF8qr4XB1n4GJBP2o&hl=en&sa=X&ei=D0jbVIDFL4m67gaBzYDoBA&ved=0CHQQ6AEwDQ#v=onepage&q=for%20asymptotic%20positive%20function%20f%28n%29%20o%28f%28n%29%29%20%3D&f=false

Comment: why didnt correct your answer?

Comment: Sorry, totaly forget about that

Comment: please correct to accept it

Comment: what about (3) ? are u sure?

Comment: I noticed i did some confusion in the 3°, edited. The point is: every problem is easyer than a NP-complete problem, so it can't be a condition that lead to the NP-completness

Comment: i sure the (1) is false.

Comment: Ah, crap, I've seen my error. Ye, what i wrote is false. Let me think for something against

Comment: it's not bounded !